# hide and show div only two divs at time with animation using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

```
<div id="container">
                    <div id='div1' style="display:none;" class='cssdiv1'> 
                      <!-- content -->
                      <h1 style='color:#FFF7F7'>this is div 1 </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id='div2'  style="display:none;" class='cssdiv2'> 
                      <!-- content -->
                      <h1 style='color:#FFF7F7'>this is div 2 </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div id='div3' style="display:none;" class='cssdiv3'> 
                      <!-- content -->
                      <h1 style='color:#FFF7F7'>this is div 3 </h1>
                    </div>
</div>
```

I have requirement where i want to show only two div's at a time and it should be in a loop.

Comment: Once 2 divs are visible, when do you want one of them to hide and the other to become visible?
Through a button click or something?

Comment: I want to use setInterval(5000) to show and hide div.and it should be infinite.

Comment: hide and show after specific interval i.e setTimeout()

Comment: are you okay with using jQuery?

Comment: yes. you can go ahead with jQuery

Answer (score 2):

You can loop using the `length` of the elements and with `append()` on Jquery like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var toloop = $('#container > div'),
      end    = toloop.length-1,
      start  = 0;
  toloop.eq(start).fadeIn(1000,shownext);
  function shownext() {
    start < end ? start++ : start=0;
    toloop.eq(start).fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
      toloop.eq(start).prev().slideUp(800,function(){
        $('#container').append($(this))
      });
      shownext();
    },2000)
  }
})
```

```css
#container > div {
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:10px 20px;
  background:purple;
  color:white;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div><h1>this is div 1</h1></div>
  <div><h1>this is div 2</h1></div>
  <div><h1>this is div 3</h1></div>
  <div><h1>this is div 4</h1></div>
  <div><h1>this is div 5</h1></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps.... * *Changed the font color to improve readability*

```js
var counter = 1

function toggleVisibility() {
  $("#div1, #div2, #div3").hide()
  $("#div"+ counter +", #div"+(counter+1)).fadeIn(500)
  if(counter < 2)
    counter++
  else
    counter--
}

toggleVisibility()
setInterval(toggleVisibility, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id='div1' style="display:none;" class='cssdiv1'> 
    <!-- content -->
    <h1 style='color:#323232'>this is div 1 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id='div2'  style="display:none;" class='cssdiv2'> 
    <!-- content -->
    <h1 style='color:#323232'>this is div 2 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id='div3' style="display:none;" class='cssdiv3'> 
    <!-- content -->
    <h1 style='color:#323232'>this is div 3 </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```